# Align corner of html5 shape with other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to detect the distance of an element from the top of the visible window, doing something like

```
var topOfDiv = $('#content-test').offset().top;
```

and then assign that value to the Y position of an HTML5 canvas shape, so that the corner of my shape always aligns with the corner of my div.

I see that you can assign pass a variable in the javascript that draws the shape, but I can't seem to pass the value I want into that variable.

This works:

```
var grid_canvas = document.getElementById("uniqueID");
var grid = grid_canvas.getContext("2d");
var spot = 0;

grid.lineTo(200,spot);
```

But grid.lineTo(200,topOfDiv); does not.

Any help is greatly appreciated.